# List all subcategories from category

Tags: categories

How can I get all subcategories from a certain category?

Comment: As explained here, you can alternatively use get_terms(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443352/how-to-get-sub-categories-by-parent-category-id-in-wordpress

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can use [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) using   `'child_of'` attribute.
For example all sub categories of category with the ID of 17:

```
$args = array('child_of' => 17);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
}
```

This will get all categories that are descendants (i.e. children & grandchildren).

If you want to display only categories that are direct descendants (i.e. children only) you can use `'parent'` attribute.

```
$args = array('parent' => 17);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
}
```

Comment: **Just a suggestion:** With the popularity of custom post types and taxonomies, i feel it would be better to be suggesting `get_terms`, because this helps familiarise users with general term fetching functions, where as the category functions are somewhat specific to the built-in taxonomy(though not in all cases). You don't have to agree of course, it's just a suggestion... ;)

Comment: I agree that [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) might be better.

Comment: @t31os - could you post an answer using `get_terms` please?

Comment: please note, by default, this will not get you categories that has no post associated with them. use `hide_empty => false` to get all categories (as per the recent version of wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

For custom post types "categories" use [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/).

(Altering @Bainternet's answer)

```
            $categories = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'parent' => 17 // or 
                //'child_of' => 17 // to target not only direct children
            ) );
            
            foreach($categories as $category) { 
                echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
                echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
                echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
            }
```